# Count occurrences in 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, compare

I'm trying to count the occurrences per line from a text file containing a large amount of codes (numbers).

Example of text file content:

```
9045,9107,2376,9017
2387,4405,4499,7120
9107,2376,3559,3488
9045,4405,3559,4499
```

I want to compare a similar set of numbers that I get from a text field, for example:

`9107,4405,2387,4499`

The only result I'm looking for, is if it contains more than 2 numbers (per line) from the text file.  So in this case it will be true, because:

9045,**9107**,2376,9017 - false (1)
**2387**,**4405**,**4499**,7120 - true (3)
**9107**,**2387**,3559,3488 - false (2)
9045,4425,3559,4490 - false (0)

From what I understand, the best way to do this, is by using a 2d-array, and I've managed to get the file imported successfully:

```java
Scanner in = null;
try { 
    in = new Scanner(new File("areas.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
List < String[] > lines = new ArrayList < > ();
while ( in .hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in .nextLine().trim();
    String[] splitted = line.split(", ");
    lines.add(splitted);
}

String[][] result = new String[lines.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = lines.get(i);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
```

The result I get:

```
[[9045,9107,2376,9017], [2387,4405,4499,7120], [9107,2376,3559,3488], [9045,4405,3559,4499], [], []]
```

From here I'm a bit stuck on checking the codes individually per line.  Any suggestions or advice?  Is the 2d-array the best way of doing this, or is there maybe an easier or better way of doing it?

Comment: If you are checking lines individually you shouldn't use a 2D array but stream the lines (e.g. using `Files.lines()`) and split/parse each into individual components. Then loop over those components and check how many are included in the input set (use a set for the elements taken from the input field for performance reasons - you don't need order here, right?). Streaming individual lines will work better with large input files.

Comment: You could directly check for the occurrences in the first loop and only store the result (true/false) somewhere. Comparing can be done in its own method which takes a String[] as input and returns true/false. Inside you have a nested for-loop iterating over the String[] and the list of given numbers to be found. Increment a counter whenever you found a match. This logic can short-circuit in the outer loop and return false after 2x false and true after 3x true (no need to do the full loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected number of inputs defines the type of searching algorithm you should use.

If you aren't searching through thousands of lines then a simple algorithm will do just fine. When in doubt favour simplicity over complex and hard to understand algorithms.

While it is not an efficient algorithm, in most cases a simple nested for-loop will do the trick.

A simple implementation would look like this:

```java
final int FOUND_THRESHOLD = 2;

String[] comparedCodes = {"9107", "4405", "2387", "4499"};
String[][] allInputs = {
    {"9045", "9107", "2376", "9017"}, // This should not match
    {"2387", "4405", "4499", "7120"}, // This should match
    {"9107", "2376", "3559", "3488"}, // This should not match
    {"9045", "4405", "3559", "4499"}, // This should match
};

List<String[] > results = new ArrayList<>();
for (String[] input: allInputs) {
    int numFound = 0;

    // Compare the codes
    for (String code: input) {
        for (String c: comparedCodes) {
            if (code.equals(c)) {
                numFound++;
                break; // Breaking out here prevents unnecessary work
            }
        }

        if (numFound >= FOUND_THRESHOLD) {
            results.add(input);
            break; // Breaking out here prevents unnecessary work
        }
    }
}

for (String[] result: results) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

which provides us with the output:

```
[2387, 4405, 4499, 7120]
[9045, 4405, 3559, 4499]
```

Comment: The code above is perfect, exactly what I wanted.  I however couldn't figure out why it didn't work when importing the numbers from a file.  Eventually found that you have a space after each comma in your example, where my text file doesn't.  Added a space and it works!

** Never mind, found the issue with the spaces.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, here's a rough outline of what you could do:

```
String textFieldContents = ... //get it

//build a set of the user input by splitting at commas 
//a stream is used to be able to trim the elements before collecting them into a set
Set<String> userInput = Arrays.stream(textFieldContents .split(","))
                              .map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toSet());

//stream the lines in the file
List<Boolean> matchResults = Files.lines(Path.of("areas.txt"))
         //map each line to true/false
        .map(line -> {          
           //split the line and stream the parts
           return Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
                        //trim each part
                        .map(String::trim) 
                        //select only those contained in the user input set
                        .filter(part -> userInput.contains(part))
                        //count matching elements and return whether there are more than 2 or not
                        .count() > 2l;          
        })
        //collect the results into a list, each element position should correspond to the zero-based line number
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you need to collect the matching lines instead of a flag per line you could replace `map()` with `filter()` (same content) and change the result type to `List<String>`.